# UITableViewcell image will display in next view of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I can take photo by camera and save in document folder. Image will load in `UITableView`.
If I select the particular row the correspondence image will go to next view and display the image.
Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Enter into cellforRow");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *FileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test1.png"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileName];

    //image
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0)];

    [imageView setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    return cell;
}
```

Now what to add in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following lines in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIImage *image = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    ImageViewController *viewer = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewer.selectedImage = image;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewer animated:YES];
```

Make a property of UIImage instace in `ImageViewController.h`

like `@property (nonatomic , retain) UIImage *selectedImage;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to show the image in subview controller.

1. Define a property in subViewController and before navigate to the subViewController assign the value in parentViewController.
2. Before navigate to subViewController pass the image path. In the subViewController show the image based on the imagePath.